# Guard gem - no such file or directory ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

I'm currently reading the third Chapter of the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages).In the last section where we set up Guard I get an error when I try to run all tests:

```
21:48:12 - INFO - Running: all tests
guard(main)> - No such file or directory - bin/rails test test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb test/test_helper.rb
```

I'm not sure why this is happening because when I run that ***rails test*** command from the command line it works as expected.

GUARDFILE:

```
# Defines the matching rules for Guard.
guard :minitest, spring: "bin/rails test", all_on_start: false do
  watch(%r{^test/(.*)/?(.*)_test\.rb$})
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { 'test' }
  watch('config/routes.rb')    { integration_tests }
  watch(%r{^app/models/(.*?)\.rb$}) do |matches|
    "test/models/#{matches[1]}_test.rb"
  end
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.*?)_controller\.rb$}) do |matches|
    resource_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/views/([^/]*?)/.*\.html\.erb$}) do |matches|
    ["test/controllers/#{matches[1]}_controller_test.rb"] +
        integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/helpers/(.*?)_helper\.rb$}) do |matches|
    integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch('app/views/layouts/application.html.erb') do
    'test/integration/site_layout_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb') do
    integration_tests << 'test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb') do
    ['test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb',
     'test/integration/users_login_test.rb']
  end
  watch('app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb') do
    'test/integration/users_signup_test.rb'
  end
  watch(%r{app/views/users/*}) do
    resource_tests('users') +
        ['test/integration/microposts_interface_test.rb']
  end
end

# Returns the integration tests corresponding to the given resource.
def integration_tests(resource = :all)
  if resource == :all
    Dir["test/integration/*"]
  else
    Dir["test/integration/#{resource}_*.rb"]
  end
end

# Returns the controller tests corresponding to the given resource.
def controller_test(resource)
  "test/controllers/#{resource}_controller_test.rb"
end

# Returns all tests for the given resource.
def resource_tests(resource)
  integration_tests(resource) << controller_test(resource)
end
```

Comment: We'll need to see the code you have to be able to find any problems. Or is the code as seen in the book failing?

Comment: @OneNeptune Yes, the code is the same as the one in the book.

Comment: Please add your `Guardfile` to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after a LOT of messing around I simply deleted the

```
spring: "bin/rails test"
```

on the very first line. This fixed everything and the test suite runs automatically now.

Comment: Seems like it tries to add "bin/rails test" to the path to lookup the files, but this pattern doesn't work. Maybe a change in 5.1.4? Maybe M.Hartl will update the example guardfile - I just copied his and had that error.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by switching from

```
guard :minitest, spring: 'bin/rails test', all_on_start: false do
```

to

```
guard :minitest, spring: 'rake test', all_on_start: false do
```

My setup
   rails: 5.0.1
   ruby: 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290

Got inspiration after reading [this post](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/issues/130)

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 10 and deleting **"bin/"** from the second line worked from me. It will then look like this:

```
guard :minitest, spring: "rails test", all_on_start: false do
```